# SlickGrid drag and sort on same cell

Tags: slickgrid

My question is if it is possible or someone has a good tutorial for making a SlickGrid row able to drag and drop somewhere but at the same be able to sort the grid aswell. Something like how 2 jquery connected sortables work.

Answer (score 0):

SlickGrid gtihub has a perfectly good example here.
http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example9-row-reordering.html